# x and y in k cross validation have different number of rows when testing the model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Using the train and test dataset from the titanic, I am trying to predict if a passenger survived or not in the titanic based on their sex. I want to build a classification and then test and evaluate it, in order to achieve my goal.

But I am getting this error :

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [418, 891]

from this line :

```
scores = cross_val_score(Model, cross_val_X, cross_val_Y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
```

I understand that the cross_val_X, cross_val_Y have different number of rows and therefore the error. Am I right or wrong ? What should I do to fix the error ?

I also want to test my model on the test dataset and I think I need to change the data that I am providing the predict method. Is that right ?

```
import pandas as pd   #data processing, CSV File(I/O)  
import numpy as np    #linear algebra
from google.colab import files
import io

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier   # K-Nearest Neighbours

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report #Build a text report showing the classification metrics.
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score #Accuracy classification score.
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix #Compute confusion matrix to evaluate the accuracy of a classification.

#Visualization Libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns

#for cross validation , import k-folder
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

#upload the file to train the model
uploaded = files.upload()  #select the path to train.csv => upload from local drive 
df_train = pd.read_excel('train_updated.xlsx') 

df_train2 = df_train.copy()

#upload the files to test the model
uploaded = files.upload()  #select the path to train.csv => upload from local drive
df_test = pd.read_csv('test_updated.csv', delimiter=';')  #reads our data and saves it in a data structure called DataFrame, splits into columns 

print('\n Head of the file: train_updated.xlsx')
print(df_train.head())        #print the head(=the first 5 rows) of the csv, to see features and target variable
              
print('\n Data info of the file: train_updated.xlsx')      #to see if there is any NaN value and length of this data
print(df_train.info() )

print('\n Data info of the file:  test')      #to see if there is any NaN value and length of this data
print(df_test.info() )

#1st pivot 
print('How many women and men survived?')
sex_pivot = df_train2.pivot_table(index="Sex",values="Survived")
sex_pivot.plot.bar()
plt.show()

#replace all nan with 0 
df_train.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
df_test.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)

#convert to int 
df_test['Embarked'].replace(( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2}), inplace=True) 

#df_test = df_test.drop(columns=['PassengerId', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Cabin', 'Ticket', 'Fare'])  
#print('\n AFTER DROPPING COLUMNS \n FILE: test')
#print(df_test.info)

#Splitting data 
#Our input will be every column except ‘Survived’ because ‘Survived’ is what we will be attempting to predict. Therefore, ‘Survived’ will be our target.

#separate target values(Y)
Y = df_train['Survived'].values.reshape(-1, 1)    
print('\n Y: target value')          #view target values
print(Y.shape) 
#convert to int 
df_train['Embarked'].replace(( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2}), inplace=True) 

#separate input values(X)
df_train = df_train.drop(columns=['Survived', 'PassengerId', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Cabin', 'Ticket', 'Fare'])  
print('\n AFTER DROPPING COLUMNS \n  file: train.csv')
print(df_train.info)
    
X = df_train['Sex_Boolean'].values.reshape(-1, 1)                                #create a dataframe with all training data except the target column

print('\n X: input data and shape ')
print(X)
print(X.shape)

#train_test_split: splits data arrays into two subsets: for training data and for testing data
#1st parameter= input data, 2nd parameter= data target 
#train_test_split will split our data set and will return 4 values, the train attributes (X_train), test attributes (X_test), train labels (y_train) and the test labels (y_test). 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y , train_size=0.7, test_size=0.3)        # 70% training and 30% test .
print('After: Train data split')
print('X_train: ', X_train.shape)
print('X_test: ', X_test.shape)
print('y_train: ', y_train.shape)
print('y_test: ', y_test.shape )

#OPTIMAL K --> PLOT 
# try K=1 through K=25 and record testing accuracy
k_range = range(1, 26)

# We can create Python dictionary using [] or dict()
scores = []

# We use a loop through the range 1 to 26
# We append the scores in the dictionary
for k in k_range:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
    scores.append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

# allow plots to appear within the notebook
%matplotlib inline

# plot the relationship between K and testing accuracy
plt.plot(k_range, scores)
plt.xlabel('Value of K for KNN')
plt.ylabel('Testing Accuracy')

# K-Nearest Neighbours Algorithm 
Model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)   #initialization

Model.fit(X_train, y_train)   #train the model
y_pred = Model.predict(X_test) 

# Summary of the predictions made by the classifier
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

# Accuracy score  
print('Accuracy is ',accuracy_score(y_pred,y_test))                      # round(knn.score(X_train, Y_train) * 100, 2)
#K-fold cross-validation

cross_val_knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
cross_val_X
try:
   cross_val_X=(df_test['Sex_Boolean'].values.reshape(-1, 1)  )# df_test['Pclass','Age','SibSp','Parch','Embarked','Sex_Boolean']  pd.get_dummies(
except KeyError:
   print("column sex boolean cannot be found")
print( "cross val x: ",  cross_val_X )
cross_val_Y= Y    
print( "cross val y: ",  cross_val_Y )

print( "SHAPE X AND Y : ",  cross_val_X.shape,  cross_val_Y.shape )

# X,y will automatically devided by 5 folder, the scoring I will still use the accuracy
scores = cross_val_score(Model, cross_val_X, cross_val_Y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
```

results:

```
 Head of the file: train_updated.xlsx
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass  ... Cabin Embarked  Sex_Boolean
0            1         0       3  ...   NaN        S            1
1            2         1       1  ...   C85        C            0
2            3         1       3  ...   NaN        S            0
3            4         1       1  ...  C123        S            0
4            5         0       3  ...   NaN        S            1

[5 rows x 13 columns]

 Data info of the file: train_updated.xlsx
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 891 entries, 0 to 890
Data columns (total 13 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   PassengerId  891 non-null    int64  
 1   Survived     891 non-null    int64  
 2   Pclass       891 non-null    int64  
 3   Name         891 non-null    object 
 4   Sex          891 non-null    object 
 5   Age          714 non-null    float64
 6   SibSp        891 non-null    int64  
 7   Parch        891 non-null    int64  
 8   Ticket       891 non-null    object 
 9   Fare         891 non-null    int64  
 10  Cabin        204 non-null    object 
 11  Embarked     889 non-null    object 
 12  Sex_Boolean  891 non-null    int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(7), object(5)
memory usage: 90.6+ KB
None

 Data info of the file:  test
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 418 entries, 0 to 417
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   PassengerId  418 non-null    int64  
 1   Pclass       418 non-null    int64  
 2   Name         418 non-null    object 
 3   Sex          418 non-null    object 
 4   Age          332 non-null    float64
 5   SibSp        418 non-null    int64  
 6   Parch        418 non-null    int64  
 7   Ticket       418 non-null    object 
 8   Fare         417 non-null    float64
 9   Cabin        91 non-null     object 
 10  Embarked     418 non-null    object 
 11  Sex_Boolean  418 non-null    int64  
dtypes: float64(2), int64(5), object(5)
memory usage: 39.3+ KB
None
How many women and men survived?


 Y: target value
(891, 1)

 AFTER DROPPING COLUMNS 
  file: train.csv
<bound method DataFrame.info of      Pclass   Age  SibSp  Parch  Embarked  Sex_Boolean
0         3  22.0      1      0         0            1
1         1  38.0      1      0         1            0
2         3  26.0      0      0         0            0
3         1  35.0      1      0         0            0
4         3  35.0      0      0         0            1
..      ...   ...    ...    ...       ...          ...
886       2  27.0      0      0         0            1
887       1  19.0      0      0         0            0
888       3   0.0      1      2         0            0
889       1  26.0      0      0         1            1
890       3  32.0      0      0         2            1

[891 rows x 6 columns]>

 X: input data and shape 
[[1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
....
[1]
 [1]]
(891, 1)
After: Train data split
X_train:  (623, 1)
X_test:  (268, 1)
y_train:  (623, 1)
y_test:  (268, 1)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:136: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
..
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:136: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().

      precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00       174
           1       0.35      1.00      0.52        94

    accuracy                           0.35       268
   macro avg       0.18      0.50      0.26       268
weighted avg       0.12      0.35      0.18       268

Accuracy is  0.35074626865671643
cross val x:  [[1]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]
....
[1]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]]

cross val y:  [[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]...
[0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]]
SHAPE X AND Y :  (418, 1) (891, 1)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:136: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-7748c3e3a4a7> in <module>()
    184 
    185 # X,y will automatically devided by 5 folder, the scoring I will still use the accuracy
--> 186 scores = cross_val_score(Model, cross_val_X, cross_val_Y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
    187 
    188 # print all 3 times scores

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:
    211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    213 
    214 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [418, 891]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a bit hard to follow, since there is quite a lot of code. Though it seems that `Y` is:

```
Y = df_train['Survived'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

And then you assign it to `cross_val_Y= Y`. Whereas `cross_val_X` comes from `df_test`:

```
cross_val_X=(df_test['Sex_Boolean'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

So it looks like they will indeed have different shapes, which would explain the issue, since as stated in the docs, the expected arrays must have shape:

> X: array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)
>   The data to fit. Can be for example a list, or an array.
>
> y: array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs), default=None
>   The target variable to try to predict in the case of supervised learning.

So the amount of samples `n_samples` has to be the same.

Comment: So, instead of  (-1, 1) I should write something like that: (418, 1) ?                                                I also posted the results.

Comment: No, you should cross validate with equally sized arrays @AlwaysLearning

Comment: But isn't it better if we use data that the model hasn't seen before so that the evaluation will be more accurate ? I wanted to to the evaluation of the model with data that the model has not seen before. This is why I used the the df_test for cross_val_X. But the problem is that in the test dataset there is not the column survived and therefore the error @yatu

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right and is internally handled by `cross_val_score`. I'd suggest you to read on it, for example https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/ @always

Comment: What do you mean with : is internally handled by cross_val_score?

Comment: Cross validation uses kfold to avergae the score on multiple unseen samples. Please read on it, it's rather long to explain. But the point is that it does not compute the score on seen samples @always

Comment: What about my second question? If I want to test the classifier that I trained using the test_dataset, can I use just the following: test_predictions = Model.predict(df_test) print('test_predictions: ', test_predictions)  ?  And then how can I compare the results of the predictions with the labels ? @yatu

Answer (score 1):

As an extra to what @yatu said, `cross_val_score` should take `model, X,Y` as arguments, you do not need to fit different values again [link to cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)
Look at the code snippet they present

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
print(cross_val_score(lasso, X, y, cv=3))
```

If you want to measure performance on a holdout set (or test_set) as you say, you should do the following in your code and maybe change the `scorer` parameter in `cross_val_score`:

```
for k in k_range:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    score = cross_val_score(knn, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scorer=None)
    scores.append(score)
```

The `cross_val_score` is already predicting on a hold_out set itself, so you do not need to do `preds = knn.predict(X_test); accuracy_score(preds, y_test)`

Comment: I wanted to to the evaluation of the model with data that the model has not seen before. This is why I used the the df_test for cross_val_X. But the problem is that in the test dataset there is not the column survived and therefore the error @DaveR

Comment: I modified my answer to explain you how/where you should use `cross_val_score` @AlwaysLearning